# Removing listeners / scoping issues

Tags: javascript, listener, addeventlistener, removeeventlistener

In a project with a soft page transition I have a hard time killing all redundant listeners. On a page-change the removeEventListeners function is called. However I'm not able to remove the listeners on the window.

I know the variable scoping in the first code example is wrong. And I've been trying to fix it in the second example. Unsuccessfully. Any ideas?

```
export default class Slider extends Core {
    init() {
        const swiper = new Swiper('.mySlider', {
            slidesOffsetBefore: this.sliderOffset(),
        });

        window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
            swiper.params.slidesOffsetBefore = this.sliderOffset();
            swiper.update();
        });
    }
    removeEventListeners() {
       // this doesn't work since there is no function reference
       window.removeEventListener('resize');
    }

    sliderOffset() {
       // does stuff and...
       return value
    }
}
```

This doesn't seem to work either...

```
export default class Slider extends Core {
    init() {
        this.swiper = new Swiper('.mySlider', {
            slidesOffsetBefore: this.sliderOffset(),
        });

        window.addEventListener('resize', this.updateSwiper);
    }

    updateSwiper() {
        this.swiper.params.slidesOffsetBefore = this.sliderOffset();
        this.swiper.update();
    }
    
    removeEventListeners() {
       window.removeEventListener('resize', this.updateSwiper);
    }

    sliderOffset() {
       // does stuff and...
       return value
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use your second example, but above your addEventListener, you can use `this.updateSwiper = this.updateSwiper.bind(this)` to set updateSwriper to a bound version of your updateSwiper function

Comment: Side note, I discovered that [RxJS](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/fromevent) can create an Observable from an event with `fromEvent(window, "resize")`, and then you subscribe to it : `fromEvent(...).subscribe(callback)`. When you no longer need it, all you have to do is `.unsubscribe()`. Since then, I stopped using `addEventListener` altogether.